# Laravel 5.2 / Socialite FatalErrorException in AbstractProvider.php line 134:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

Getting the following error when using Socialite to authenticate with Facebook.  Using Laravel 5.2 and this is the first time I am trying to implement Socialite.  Any ideas ?

```
FatalErrorException in AbstractProvider.php line 134:
Call to a member function set() on a non-object
```

Route :-

```
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login');
```

AuthController.php :-

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
public function login()
{
  return \Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}
}
```

services.php setup as follows with details in the .env file :-

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id'     => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT'),
],
```

The same error was reported here but no response :- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-socialite-session-errors-in-52/replies/125233

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem...

Found an answer here: [in routes.php, did you define your routes inside the web middleware group? This seems to be a common problem with 5.2 upgrades :)](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-socialite-session-errors-in-52)

It looks like you have to put your routes in a MiddleWare because it includes Session creation which is needed in the AbstractProvider.php 134

```
$this->request->getSession()->set('state', $state = Str::random(40));
```

This is how my code routes.php looks like now (and works):

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('admin_template');
});

Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
    Route::get('auth/google', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
    Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');

});
```

Comment: Just seen that you had the same link already with the answer now available ... good to keep it up here though. I am now struggling with the callback as there is no user and it throws an invalid state.

Comment: Putting the Route in the web middleware fixed it.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are receiving this error is because there is no session started. You have to assign the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` middleware to the route your calling.

In previous version of Laravel this was already assigned within the `$middleware` property, found in the file `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your route.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');

    Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthController@callback');

});
```